# Voltage range of a differential pressure sensor px26, and opamp saturation

Tags: arduino, voltage, sensor

Im using a px26 001GV differential pressure sensor for a project with arduino, here is the data sheet. (http://www.omega.com/manuals/manualpdf/M1608.pdf)
Now, I have few questions regarding this.

1) I'm using this around a valve to know the differential pressure, lets say side A and side B
Now if side A>B i get a positive voltage in milli volts, what if side B>A would it give a negative voltage? so would I get a range of voltages for its full functionality from negative to positive like say -8mv to +8mv?

2)I'm using an op amp to amplify the reading so I could amplify 8.6mv to 1.8V and then the opamp saturates, is there any way around this?

3) the opamp AD620AN which is a instrumental amp to be precise , needs voltage ranges -5 t0 +5 so i used a 10 volts dc, made a voltage divider, created a virtual ground. So what if I connect this system to arduino (0to5V range) would the divider cut off the system to (-2.5 to +2.5)?If so, should I check my circuit by using a 5V Dc and using the divider and check how the opamp responds?

PS: I'm new to this , please try to avoid all the electrical lingo, I wouldn't understand it. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Note that the "virtual ground" made with the divider MUT be the ARduino true ground if interfacing the opamp/instamp directly to the Arduino without level shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to remember about the AD620 (and other instumentation amps and most opamps) is that their inputs only work correctly when the voltages applied to them are within a limited range. This limited range is governed by the power rails.

For instance, the AD620 data sheet says: -

```
Input Voltage Range = -Vs+1.9 volts to +Vs-1.2 volts
```

This means, that for a +/-5V supply, the valid input voltage range is: -

```
-3.1 volts to +3.8 volts.
```

For a 0 to 10V supply it is: -

```
+1.9 volts to 8.8 volts.
```

Whatever you do, make sure you don't get too close to these limits or you'll get disappointing results. Next is the output voltage swing. The data sheet says this: -

```
Output voltage range = -Vs+1.1 volts to +Vs-1.2 volts
```

For a 0 to 10V supply this means the output can fall as low as +1.1 volts and rise as high as 3.8 volts.

If you can get your sensor to input the right voltage range that's a start. Next, use the REF pin to bias the output so that it remains within the output limits imposed above and finally, try using a potential divider to reduce the output range that that suitable for your arduino.

One last bit of advice - read the data sheet and keep asking questions if there is something you don't understand in the data sheet. A lot of the more experienced guys on this site will tell you that the data sheet is all you have - no belief system involved except to believe the manufacturers have told the truth - invariably they have of course.

Comment: I have tried to read the data sheet but, i dont really understand many terms in it, so as you said about the input ranges im using millivolts, that would do right falling within ranges? what i dont understand is why is it saturating when im within the range? im new to all this so bear with my understanding ability.

Comment: I think a circuit diagram would help - if you post one somewhere someone will undoubtedy paste it into your question

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get something straight - if you come to an electrical engineering forum, and ask for advice about an electrical circuit, you are just going to have to expect "electrical lingo".

With a 10 volt excitation, according to the data sheet you should expect a +/- 16.8 mV on your sensor outputs, centered around 5 volts.

Because you have created a virtual ground, your outputs and inputs have to be in terms of the virtual ground, not the circuit ground. Your sensor will provide the input levels you need, but I believe you've gotten yourself in trouble with the reference.

If you look at the data sheet http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf bottom of page 4, you will see that the reference input range is -Vs + 1.6, and I bet you've tied it to circuit ground. Right? So you're operating the AD620 outside its range.

What you need to do is provide an offset on the AD620 output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiFlES.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The two op amps should be general-purpose types with rail-to-rail outputs. The AD620 gain should be set to give +/- 2.5 volts. The output of op amp 2 will be 0 to 5 volts.

And make sure you use 1% resistors.

Comment: hi, i donot know how to ad a picture here, so i posted an answer, please check it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOrry, I'm nt from an electrical background so it was hard for me to understand those words.

I'm attaching a picture of my circuit, i think i connected it to the circuit ground. And also i have to use this sensor with arduino which works with 0 to 5, so then would my voltage divider make -2.5 to +2.5? would my circuit be valid then?
[image]